# Total number of UNIQUE rotations in a 3D array around an axis

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, 3d, rotation

How many number of unique rotations are there in a 3D array around an axis. For example: a 3x3x3 array can be rotated 8 (rotation = single roll/shift in element - One rotation of the cube is rotating all the slices around one axis by 1 element. ) times around each axis. However, with all three axis, there are 8*8*8 rotations. But how many of them are unique?
In my calculation, there are 208. And in a 5x5x5 3D array, out of total of 13824 rotations (24*24*24) only 2048 are unique. 
I would like if someone can confirm these or correct me if I am wrong.

I used the following script to generate these.

```
def rotateSlice(slice_data, num_elements=1, direction='c'):
    if direction == 'ac':
        num_elements *= -1
    rotated_slice = slice_data
    indexed_slice = numpy.arange(0, slice_data.shape[0]**2).reshape(slice_data.shape)
    int_slice_idx = 0
    for i in range(slice_data.shape[0], 1, -2):
        clipped_array = slice_data[int_slice_idx:slice_data.shape[0]-int_slice_idx, int_slice_idx:slice_data.shape[0]-int_slice_idx]
        clipped_indx_array = indexed_slice[int_slice_idx:slice_data.shape[0]-int_slice_idx, int_slice_idx:slice_data.shape[0]-int_slice_idx]
        outer_border = list(range(i)) + list(range(range(i)[-1]+i, i*(i-2)+range(i)[-1]+i, i)) + list(range(i**2 - 1, i**2 - (i+1), -1)) + list(range(i*(i-2), 0, -i))
        new_outer_border = numpy.roll(outer_border, num_elements)
        rotated_slice.flat[clipped_indx_array.flat[outer_border]] = clipped_array.flat[new_outer_border]
        int_slice_idx +=1
    return rotated_slice


def rotateCube(cube, rotate_dim, num_elements=1, direction='c'):
    out_cube = numpy.zeros(cube.shape, dtype='int')
    for i in range(cube.shape[rotate_dim]):
        slice = numpy.take(cube, i, rotate_dim)
        rotated_slice = rotateSlice(slice, num_elements=num_elements, direction=direction)

        #TODO - Its better if there is a less ugly way to do the following step. Similar to numpy.take
        if rotate_dim == 0:
            out_cube[i,:,:] = rotated_slice
        elif rotate_dim == 1:
            out_cube[:, i, :] = rotated_slice
        elif rotate_dim == 2:
            out_cube[:, :, i] = rotated_slice
    return out_cube


def getAllCubeRotations(cube, step=1, direction='c'):
    total_rotations_in_axis = cube.shape[0]**2 - 1
    rotations = []
    for i in range(int(total_rotations_in_axis)):
        cube = rotateCube(cube, rotate_dim=0, num_elements=step, direction=direction)
        for j in range(int(total_rotations_in_axis)):
            cube = rotateCube(cube, rotate_dim=1, num_elements=step, direction=direction)
            for k in range(int(total_rotations_in_axis)):
                cube = rotateCube(cube, rotate_dim=2, num_elements=step, direction=direction)
                rotations.append(cube)
    return rotations


if __name__ == '__main__':
    size = 5
    a = numpy.arange(0, size*size*size).reshape((size,size,size))
    rotations = getAllCubeRotations(a)
    print(len(rotations))
    uniques = []
    for arr in rotations:
        if not any(numpy.array_equal(arr, unique_arr) for unique_arr in uniques):
            uniques.append(arr)
    print(len(uniques))
```

Comment: I wonder how you define a *rotation* - is it a 90° rotation? I.e. for a ``3**3`` cube a *flip* to one of the other faces, such that the general face orientation remains the same?

Comment: Nope. A rotation in this case is a roll (shift) of a single element. So for a 3**3 cube, A 90 degree roation will be 2 shifts.

Comment: Perhaps you should elaborate on your definition of *rotation* here. I personally am stuck somewhere between rotations of an entire cube in 3D and a 'partial' rotation like in one of the layers of a *Rubik's Cube*...

Comment: I will try to elaborate more. One rotation of the cube is rotating all the slices around one axis by 1 element. So in the case of the rubik's cube; the whole cube is rotated. Not a layer.